# MongoDb. Flatten inner array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection containing documents with the following structure:

```
{  
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": [
        {
          "baz": [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        },
        {
          "baz": [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "bar": [
        {
          "baz": [
            7,
            8,
            9
          ]
        },
        {
          "baz": [
            10,
            11,
            12
          ]
        }
      ]
    }        
  ]
}
```

And I want to get a flat array containing all values from all "bar" arrays. In other words result I want looks like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
How could I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation using [**`$reduce`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "array": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$foo",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$this.bar", "$$value"] }       
          }
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$this.baz", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y69An__xcUH)

**Or** using [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$foo" },
  { "$unwind": "$foo.bar" },
  { "$unwind": "$foo.bar.baz" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "array": {
      "$push": "$foo.bar.baz"
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9A5rEe-K14r)

Comment: which one will be the faster query? $unwind or $reduce ?

Comment: @VikashSingh `$unwind` always deconstruct the array and creates copy of document according to 
 the array size. So of course the first one `$reduce` is the better options